# Transform a stateless Wrap function to a component with state in react

Tags: reactjs

i would like to create a wrapper component in react, and i need to pass some states to the child components.

The error message i get is:

**Failed to compile.**

**./src/app/layouts/MainLayout.jsx**

**Line 9:   'children' is not defined  no-undef**

**Line 77:  'Children' is not defined  no-undef**

Thats the the Wrapper component: MainLayout.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { Row, Col, Alert } from 'reactstrap'
import PortfolioTitle from './components/sidemodules/PortfolioTitle';
import AppMenu from './components/menu/AppMenu';

const Api = require('./api/PortfolioApi')

class MainLayout extends Component ({ children }) {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      portfolio: {
        id: this.getPortfolioId(props),
      },
      redirect: null,
      errors: []
    }
  }

  getPortfolioId(props) {
    try {
      return props.match.params.id
    } catch (error) {
      return null
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.portfolio.id) {
      Api.getPortfolio(this.state.portfolio.id)
        .then(response => {
          const [error, data] = response
          if (error) {
            this.setState({
              errors: data
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              portfolio: data,
              errors: []
            })
          }
        })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { redirect, portfolio, errors } = this.state

    if (redirect) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={redirect} />
      )
    } else {

      return (
        <>
            <Row>
              {errors.length > 0 &&
                <div>
                  {errors.map((error, index) =>
                    <Alert color="danger" key={index}>
                      {error}
                    </Alert>
                  )}
                </div>
              }
              <Col xl={3}>
                <PortfolioTitle portfolio={portfolio} />              
              </Col>
              <Col xl={9}>
                <AppMenu portfolio={portfolio} />

                {/* Here goes the wrapped content */}
                {Children}

              </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default MainLayout
```

This is the content that will be wrapped.

Smartfolio.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import MainLayout from './layouts/MainLayout';
import HistoricalRentability from './components/dashboard/HistoricalRentability'
import PortfolioCompostition from './components/dashboard/PortfolioComposition';

function Smartfolio(props) {
  var id = props.portfolio.id;
  return (
    <>
    <MainLayout>
          <HistoricalRentability />
          <PortfolioCompostition id={id} />
    </MainLayout>
  </>
  )
}

export default Smartfolio
```

I would like some help to understand how can i get this component working, thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you seeing that make this syntax not work? One issue I see is that the definition of the class should not have `({ children })` and instead should be `class MainLayout extends Component { ... render() }`

Comment: Sorry, but I have a hard time understanding what you want. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Sorry @nico263nico, maybe i could not explain it clear, the error message i get is: Parsing error: Identifier 'MainLayout' has already been declared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AlexeiDarmin, yes i would like to know how i can create a class that is a wrapper. in the example it would be something like: <MainLayout> Content </MainLayout> , the error i get is: Parsing error: Identifier 'MainLayout' has already been declared.

Comment: I have edited the question to see if it get more clear and understandable.

Comment: Using `({ children })` is meant for function components where props are passed as arguments. For class components, you can use `this.props.children`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component should be like this,

```
class MainLayout extends Component {

   ......

 render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      ......
      { children }
    )
 }
 
}
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html